# Send base64 img to another service (nodejs+curl)

Tags: javascript, image, node.js, curl, base64

I check many questions and find first answer here - [NodeJS: Saving a base64-encoded image to disk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6926016/nodejs-saving-a-base64-encoded-image-to-disk), it's nice and I can save img to disk. But, I see this topic [How to do Base64 encoding in node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6182315/how-to-do-base64-encoding-in-node-js) and have this question: can I send image to the third service without saving img to disk?
I have this code, it's doesn't work

```
    var url = req.body.upload_url;
    var img = req.body.img;
    var base64Data = img.replace(/^data:image\/png;base64,/,"");
    var tempIMG = new Buffer(base64Data, 'base64');

    curl(url, {
        MULTIPART: [

            {name: 'file1', file: tempIMG, type: 'image/png'},
            {name: 'sumbit', contents: 'send'}
        ]
    }, function(e) {
        log.info(this.body);
        res.json(this.body);
    });
```

I rly need to save img to the disk -> send to the servise -> delete img ? or I can use buffer, but there is mistake? If I send test file from disk - this code work.