# Create a local image file with base 64 in javascript

Tags: javascript, image, base64

I need to use javascript to create an image file on my local computer a .png or .jpg etc file, I have the base 64 of the image, can this be done?

Comment: please check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897619/using-html5-javascript-to-generate-and-save-a-file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can do it. 
All you need is:

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'data:image/gif;base64,...';
document.body.appendChild(img);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Nodejs, create a buffer with base64 encoding and write the buffer to the file

refer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/6933413/4325568

Comment: Unfortuanately I am using react-native which doesnt support Node.js