# Writing binary data using node.js fs.writeFile to create an image file

Tags: javascript, node.js, binary

I'm trying to write a canvas data with node.js [`fs.writeFile`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback) as a binary. JPEG file, but after the file is written I can see that the file is stored as plain text, not binary data.

This is an example of the `data` sent from the client to my node, representing the JPEG image data (just a few first characters):

`/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAFA3PEY8MlBGQUZaVVBfeM...`

I'm getting this `data` **on the client side** by performing:

```
canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 0.5).replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,', '')
```

Here is the function usage in my **node.js server**:

```
fs.writeFile('../some.jpeg', data, 'binary', function(err){});
```

Instead of the file being written as binary (`״״ JFIF  ...`), it writes exactly the data it received from the client.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6933413/1746830

Comment: @Rayon Thanks, I'm looking through your 1st comment

Comment: @Rayon I changed it to `fs.writeFile('../some.jpeg', data, 'base64', function(err){});` but still it writes it as the same string it received.

Comment: @Rayon `var buf = new Buffer(data, 'base64');
fs.writeFile('image.png', buf);` works ! Please post this as an answer so I can rep you.

Comment: I was just about to suggest you later option... Glad it helped...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6926804/1746830 suggests the same approach.. I think it should be marked as a dupe...

Answer (score 86, accepted):

> JavaScript language had no mechanism for reading or manipulating streams of binary data. The `Buffer` class was introduced as part of the Node.js API to make it possible to interact with octet streams in the context of things like TCP streams and file system operations.

Pure JavaScript, while great with Unicode encoded strings, does not handle straight binary data very well.

When writing large amounts of data to a socket it's much more efficient to have that data in binary format vs having to convert from Unicode.

```
var fs = require('fs');
// string generated by canvas.toDataURL()
var img = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABQAAAAUCAYAAACNiR0"
    + "NAAAAKElEQVQ4jWNgYGD4Twzu6FhFFGYYNXDUwGFpIAk2E4dHDRw1cDgaCAASFOffhEIO"
    + "3gAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==";
// strip off the data: url prefix to get just the base64-encoded bytes
var data = img.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, "");
var buf = Buffer.from(data, 'base64');
fs.writeFile('image.png', buf, /* callback will go here */);
```

[**Reference**](https://gist.github.com/madhums/e749dca107e26d72b64d)

Comment: Rayon, This works perfectly. Thanks for all your help, peace and love from Israel.

Comment: – I'm glad it helped! _Happy Coding_

Comment: *"Pure javascript... does not handle straight binary data very well."* -- I don't understand this answer, given that this is a recent Q&A. Did you completely miss `TypedArrays` and `ArrayBuffer`? Binary data is not an issue in Javascript, and while it it's "newish" it's not exactly *that* new. .https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays

Comment: @Mörre - I referred that statement from [__here__](https://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/advanced/buffers/how-to-use-buffers/)

Comment: @Rayon Which is from 2011. I refer to my comment above.

Comment: Work like a charm! Thx

Comment: You sir, are a time saver! ^_^

Comment: thanks for this, but according to this answer, `fs.write` requires a callback function: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51155728/144088. how come this works for you?

Comment: @Crashalot - I seriously did not pay attention to that callback argument. I have updated my answer. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 14):

I have had the question in question. I solved the problem when I made the default value null of "encoding" in the "request" library

```
var request = require("request").defaults({ encoding: null });
var fs = require("fs");

fs.writeFile("./image.png", body, function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
});
```

Comment: I was downloading an image file using a link and `require("request").defaults({ encoding: null });` solved my day. But, the answer can be improved a bit more.

Answer (score 3):

Use `Buffer.from`, as `Buffer` is deprecated, will get the following warning

> (node:15707) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.

```
var fs = require('fs');
// string generated by canvas.toDataURL()
var img = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABQAAAAUCAYAAACNiR0"
    + "NAAAAKElEQVQ4jWNgYGD4Twzu6FhFFGYYNXDUwGFpIAk2E4dHDRw1cDgaCAASFOffhEIO"
    + "3gAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==";
// strip off the data: url prefix to get just the base64-encoded bytes
var data = img.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, "");
var buf = Buffer.from(data, 'base64');
fs.writeFile('image.png', buf);
```

Answer (score 2):

**Instead of writing the file directly to your client, first, ask the server to send 
images in binary format.**

```
   let request= {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg',
            'Authorization': "your token"
        },
        encoding:'binary'
    };
     request.get(url,request,(error, response, body)=>{
        if(error){
            console.log('error in get photo',error)
            return "default image to server";  
        }else{
            if(response.statusCode == 200){ 

      Fs.writeFile('path',body,'binary',function(err){
                    if(err){
                        return "your message";   
                    }else{
                        return "success";
                    }
                })
            }else{
                console.log('error in get photo 3')
                return "your message";  
            }
        }
    })
```