# how to fix this error TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK]: Callback must be a function

Tags: node.js, callback

I am a beginner to the nodejs. When I type the below, the code error occurs like this:

> TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK]: Callback must be a function

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.readFile('readMe.txt', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
  fs.writeFile('writeMe.txt', data);
});
```

Answer (score 89, accepted):

`Fs.writeFile()` according to the documentation [here](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback) takes (
file, data[, options]and callback )  params so your code will be like this :

```
 var fs = require('fs');
 fs.readFile('readMe.txt', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
  fs.writeFile('writeMe.txt', data, function(err, result) {
     if(err) console.log('error', err);
   });
 });
```

Comment: Perfect! But, why are we defining a function again for writeFile as the 3rd parameter, when have the 'data' param from readFile that holds the data? Why can't we reuse the same data?

Comment: There is no need to pass the third parameter in the callback function of writeFile. The only thing is that we should pass a callback function.

Answer (score 19):

`fs.writeFile(...)` requires a third (or fourth) parameter which is a callback function to be invoked when the operation completes. You should either provide a callback function or use `fs.writeFileSync(...)`

See [node fs docs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fswritefilefile-data-options-callback) for more info.

Answer (score 12):

Since node 10, it is mandatory to pass a callback on `fs.writefile()`

Node.js documented the purpose for the change: https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/doc/api/deprecations.md#dep0013-fs-asynchronous-function-without-callback

You could add an empty callback like this `fs.writeFile('writeMe.txt', data, () => {})`

Answer (score 6):

you also use like this

```
var file2 =  fs.readFileSync("./Public/n2.jpeg")
```

Comment: There's no need to use `await` when you use `readFileSync` because, as the name suggests, `readFileSync` is [synchronous](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options).

Comment: await and readFileSync is completely redundant since readFileSync its an already sync function

Comment: When I do this I get `Callback must be a function`

Answer (score 1):

You simply could use the sync function

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.readFileSync('readMe.txt', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
  fs.writeFileSync('writeMe.txt', data);
});
```

or use callback function

Answer (score 1):

you can import the fs module from the fs/promises as they are promise-fied version of the modules so we don't need to use the callback function unnecessarily.

```
import fs from 'fs/promises';

fs.readFileSync('readMe.txt', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
fs.writeFileSync('writeMe.txt', data);`});`
```

Answer (score 1):

I went into a similar situation. I followed below.

const fs = require('fs').promises;

Now you can read/write the file with await without using any kind of callback. Here we are Promising the fs module.

const file = await fs.readFile(fileURL);

Answer (score 0):

```
var fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('readme.txt', 'utf8', function(err, data) {
    fs.writeFile('writemeee.txt', data, function(err, result) {

        if (err) console.log('error', err);

    });
});
```

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation

Answer (score 0):

try this .I have written the code using Promises.

```
const {readFile} = require('fs');
const {writeFileSync} = require('fs');
const readText = (path)=>{
 return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    readFile(path,'utf8',(err,result)=>{
      if(err)
        reject(err);
      else
        resolve(result);
      })
  })
}

readText('./contents/sample.txt')
  .then(val=>writeFileSync('./results.txt',val))
  .catch(err=>console.log(err));
```

Answer (score -1):

This error hit me in the face when I was doing the following;

`var hello = myfunction( callme() );`

rather than

`var hello = myfunction( callme );`