# Why is my code receiving undefined when writing a file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am trying to log all messages in a file for the bot on my server. However, whenever I run my bot and someone sends a message, I get this error:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK]: Callback must be a function. Received undefined

Here is my code:

```
if (message.channel.type !== 'dm')
{
var log = `[SERVER MESSAGE] ${message.member.user.tag}: "${message.content}" in #${message.channel.name}`;
  console.log(log);
  fs.writeFile("C:/Users/dubwi/Desktop/Discord_Bot/chatlog.json", `${log}`)
}
else{
  message.reply("I don't accept DMs at the moment");
  var log = `[DM MESSAGE] ${message.author.tag}: "${message.content}"`;
  console.log(log);
  fs.writeFile("C:/Users/dubwi/Desktop/Discord_Bot/chatlog.json", `${log}`)
}
```

Comment: Going through your code I'm trying to find where you are calling a function. `console.log` is fine since it's built in so it's either you're not importing fs and usiing `fs.writeFile` or `message.reply` is undefined. Try `if (message.reply) { message.reply("whatever" } else { console.log("issue is here") }`

Comment: Functions in javascript are defined like this:

    function someFunctionName(){ //do something here}
    const someFunctionName = function(){ //do something here}

All you have is an if statement, which is not a function.

Comment: [`fs.writeFile()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v13.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback) requires that a `callback` function is provided as a 3rd argument. – Related: [how to fix this error TypeError \[ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK\]: Callback must be a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51150956/how-to-fix-this-error-typeerror-err-invalid-callback-callback-must-be-a-funct)

Comment: This solved my problem, could you send this as an answer to my question so I can mark it answered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the async method (fs.writeFile -[doc](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback)), which is expecting a callback function.

So you can either use the synchronous method (fs.writeFileSync -[doc](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_file_data_options)) which does not require a callback, or modify your code to work with callbacks

Hope this helps