# Trouble with Electron showOpenDialog

Tags: javascript, promise, callback, electron

I have an Electron app that implements a `GlobalShortcut` designed to open a file and read it. I'm having an issue with the `dialog.showOpenDialog()` method:

```
// in the main process
const {dialog} = require('electron');
const {BrowserWindow} = require('electron');

app.on('ready', () => {
    globalShortcut.register('CommandOrControl+O', () => {
        const window = BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow();

        const options = {
            title: 'Pick a markdown file',
            filters: [
                { name: 'Markdown files', extensions: ['md'] },
                { name: 'Text files', extensions: ['txt'] }
            ]
        };

        dialog.showOpenDialog(window, options
            ).then(result => {
                if (result.canceled === false)
                {
                    // read the file and send it to the renderer process
                    let file = result.filePaths[0];
                    console.log(result.filePaths);
                    const content = fs.readFile(file).toString(); // this is the offending line
                    window.webContents.send('load', content);
                }
            }).catch (err => {
                console.log(err);
            });
    });
});
```

Upon running the application and giving it the Ctrl+O command, I get the following error:
`TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK]: Callback must be a function. Received undefined`

Here's a snippet from the `package.json` file:

```
"dependencies": {
    "electron": "^12.0.2",
    "electron-version": "^2.0.1",
    "simplemde": "^1.11.2"
  }
```

Isn't the `showOpenDialog` method updated to use promises instead of callbacks? What is causing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

As per this post: [how to fix this error TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK]: Callback must be a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51150956/how-to-fix-this-error-typeerror-err-invalid-callback-callback-must-be-a-funct/51151244),

the correct method to use here is `fs.readFileSync(file).toString();`. This solved the problem.