# Creating an Image File using node.js buffer from input text

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, buffer, node.js-buffer

- I have a requirement in which I need to convert an input text to a **png/jpeg** file and then convert to base64 string and send as an input to an API.
- I cannot use node.js fs module since I cannot physically create files.
- So I was trying to user node.js Buffer module to achieve the same.
- But the issue I'm facing is, I cannot add extension to it(I don't know if there is any such option).
  Is there any other way of doing so?

Below is the code I tried...

```
function textToFileBase64(str){
    var buf = Buffer.from(str, 'utf-8');
    return buf.toString('base64');

}
```

> The only problem with the above code is that it creates a file without extension and even if I need the file as abc.png, it says the file is damaged when I open it.

Comment: I got this code from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43487543/writing-binary-data-using-node-js-fs-writefile-to-create-an-image-file
var img = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABQAAAAUCAYAAACNiR0"
    + "NAAAAKElEQVQ4jWNgYGD4Twzu6FhFFGYYNXDUwGFpIAk2E4dHDRw1cDgaCAASFOffhEIO"
    + "3gAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==";
// strip off the data: url prefix to get just the base64-encoded bytes
var data = img.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, "");
var buf = new Buffer(data, 'base64');

Just wanted to understand how to create the base64 code of an image having the text I need.