# How to dynamically add images to express from react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image

I have a react app and express server. I'm currently fetching the images and displaying them. all the images are directly stored in the public folder. I was wondering if it's possible to dynamically add images to this public folder and how I would go about it?

I'd rather not store them in a database and wondered how I can upload the from react and store them in the public folder, is this possible? I know how to do the image upload in the browser, it's just the storage part?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Writing binary data using node.js fs.writeFile to create an image file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43487543/writing-binary-data-using-node-js-fs-writefile-to-create-an-image-file) Otherwise I would look at a SaaS product, like Cloudinary, if you can - they do a lot of heavy lifting and can be free / cheap