# Decoding a base64 string (png file) back to an Image

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, base64

I'm using the base-64 npm but how can it's returning random characters. Is there any way I can decode a string and product a png image file?

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6926016/nodejs-saving-a-base64-encoded-image-to-disk

Answer (score 0):

If you are using React create a component like-so:

```
class Base64Image extends React.Component{
  render() {
     return <img
       src={"data:image/jpeg;" + 
         this.props.imageBase64String} 
     />
  }
}
```

``

To use the component, 
Assuming you have a base64Image variable:

```
<Base64Image imageBase64String={base64Image} />
```