# Saving ANY FILE type base64-encoded to disk

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I came across this question [NodeJS: Saving a base64-encoded image to disk](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6926016/6143656) and only find out that this logic only create/write an IMAGE file from disk. But is there way how to save any file from NodeJS using base64-encoded string? I searched all over google but cannot find a decent solution since the result is always limited to image writing.

In case you need to look at my code:

```
// Use Buffer for decoded base64 string.
var buffer = new Buffer(decodedBase64String, 'base64');

// I used writeFile and base64 encoding option.
fs.writeFile(fullpath, buffer, 'base64', (err) => {
    // If fails handle error here..
});
```

Comment: didn't really tried but I assume you just need to replace the first line with `var base64Data = req.rawBody.substr(req.rawBody.indexOf(',')+1);`

Comment: @kaiido will try that thanks!

Comment: @Kaiido man, why dont you make that as an answer it is very helpful, i got it right thanks for pointing out just explain what's going on