# Sails.js how to convert a base64-encoded to image and store it in disk?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I'm trying to convert the base64-encoded to image but it doesn't work

```
var base64Data = req.rawBody.split(',')[1];
    require("fs").writeFile("out.png", base64Data, 'base64', function(err){
        if(err){
            console.log('err');
        }
```

Comment: here what is base64Data?

Comment: @ManjeetThakur where the base64 encoded goes

Comment: have you check this [base64-encoded-image-to-disk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6926016/nodejs-saving-a-base64-encoded-image-to-disk)

Comment: @ManjeetThakur I have :( still not working

Comment: can you show me error ?

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
    at C:\MeanMax\api\controllers\JobController.js:26:25

Comment: console.log("%j",  req.rawBody)

Comment: its say nothing

Comment: req.rawBody can you print this

Comment: its show undefined

Comment: fix this error and then split method work on it `var base64Data = req.rawBody.split(',')[1];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by request fs

```
var request = require('fs');
```

before use in controller