# Create image file in nodeJs from blob

Tags: javascript, node.js, png, blob

I am receiving **`BLOB`** data on nodeJs server which is converted from PNG image.

I need to create again png image on nodeJs server to be able to show it on pdf document.

I had tried to use FileSaver on nodeJs but it is not working.
FileSaver works well on reactJs app.

How can I save a new file to the local directory on the server?

> There is a lot question pointing on problems with creating an image file
>   form blob but I was unable to use base64encode, so other questions were
>   not helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NodeJS: Saving a base64-encoded image to disk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6926016/nodejs-saving-a-base64-encoded-image-to-disk)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In BLOB data of png image file there is **`buffer`** property.

So I used this solution to create image.

```
var imageBuffer = request.file.buffer;
var imageName = 'public/images/map.png';

fs.createWriteStream(imageName).write(imageBuffer);
```

This has solved my problem.

Comment: Apparently property 'buffer' does not exist on type 'Blob'

Answer (score 5):

```
var base64Data = req.body.image.replace(/^data:image\/png;base64,/, "");

require("fs").writeFile("out.png", base64Data, 'base64', function(err) {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Try this one here image is the name on which data is coming.