# Extract png from a base64 image

Tags: node.js, image, buffer

My image src is base64 data as bellow:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABd4AAAH ...." />
```

I want to save it as an image (like png format) by nodejs; how is it possible? I am using following code. The src is too big.and when I convert, the image is converted untill its half maybe.

```
var dt= "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABd4AAAH ...." 
let buff = Buffer.from(dt, 'base64');
fs.writeFileSync('./myImage.png', buff);
```

Comment: I can see many options to extract png from base64-encoded image on this article.  Have you ever tried them?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6926016/how-can-i-save-a-base64-encoded-image-to-disk

Comment: The problem is I think my big src length.

Comment: You need to remove the `base64,` prefix from `dt` (the actual PNG data starts with `iVBOR`).

Comment: @robertklep you are right. It was my mistake but how to deal with nodejs limitations.

Comment: If you're running into Node.js limitations, your code will crash, it will not just write half of an image.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add extra parameter to write method: "`encoding`". And value of this parameter should be encoding you want to do, in this example "`base64`"

In the end, your code should look like this:

```js
var dt= "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABd4AAAH ...." 
let buff = Buffer.from(dt, 'base64');
fs.writeFileSync('./myImage.png', buff, { encoding: "base64" });
```

Answer (score 0):

It's works but you should add encoding param

```js
var dt= "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABd4AAAH ...." 
let buff = Buffer.from(dt, 'base64');
fs.writeFileSync('./myImage.png', buff, {encoding: "base64"});
```

`encoding` parameter must be entered for correctly work.