# How to save plotly image to local file with javascript

Tags: plotly

What's proper way to save plotly graph to local file with javascript?

```
img_png.attr("src", url);
Plotly.toImage(gd,{format:'png',height:400,width:400});
```

Above code from official document save it to element, I would like to save it to local disk directly!

Comment: `fig.write_image('filename')` For details, see Saving Images in [Reference](https://plotly.com/python/static-image-export/#write-image-file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll get an image encode with base64 string from `Plotly.toImage()`, and you can convert base64 string to image in many ways.
(For example like [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6926016/how-can-i-save-a-base64-encoded-image-to-disk).)

Assume the HTML code is like this:

```html
<div id="chart">
  <!-- chart here -->
</div>
```

Then the JavaScript code should be like this:

```js
Plotly.toImage('chart', { format: 'png', width: 800, height: 600 }).then(
    function (dataUrl) {
    // use the dataUrl
})
```